# Increase clicking area around a button, not an anchor

Tags: html, css

I want to expand the clicking area of a button (not an anchor).
I already saw the examples with anchors, but that ship sailed already, I must use buttons.

There's nothing special about the button:

```
<button class="example">OK</button>
```

I tried using :before :after pseudo

```
.example {
        position: relative;
}   
.example::before {
        outline: 1px solid red;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: -10px;
        bottom: -10px;
        left: -10px;
        right: -10px;
    }
```

I see the outline, I can also click it in Chrome. Not in Firefox though.
I need a different approach.

Comment: Put a button inside another button? Make the outer button transparent background.

Comment: Have you tried setting `.example` to be relative? Have you tried padding on `.example`?

Comment: Are you allowed to change the html? Can you add something around the button tag?

Comment: Justinas, yes, .example is relative.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish by exapnding the clicking area and why can't you just do it by increasing the size of the button itself?

Comment: I guess I could add things around the button or inside it to make it work. But I can't go from a button to anchor.

Comment: AsheraH, I already increased the size, buy the need is to also have a portion around the button be clickable for that specific button. I can only increase them so much until they look ridiculous.

Comment: Not realated, I specified in title that I am NOT using anchors. Also in comments I said I can't go to that.

Comment: Unlike inputs, buttons can have inner HTML content. So, try adding a span or something inside the button and add the css to the inner html element and make button background transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KiranKumarDash/vb4zuuwa/)

Buttons can have inner HTML content.

So, Add a span or something inside the button and add the css to the inner html element and make button background transparent

**HTML:**

```
<button onclick="myFunction()"><span>TEST</span></button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("I am an alert box!");
}
</script>
```

**css:**

```
button{
  background: transparent;
  border: none; 
  outline: none; // removes button's default styles
  padding: 50px 100px; // increases the button's area
}

span{
    background: #000; 
    color: #fff; 
    padding: 20px; // This is the visible area inside the button
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KiranKumarDash/vb4zuuwa/)

Comment: Your fiddle is using a link, not a button. Should update it to reflect the same code as shown here in your answer.

Comment: It works. It might take some time, but it's the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: Your fiddle code is different from above code, you must update your fiddle

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Abhishek. I updated the fiddle too.

Answer (score 1):

I find this solution for you.
You can change the clicking area on `.example` and the "fake button" style in the `:before pseudo`.

My code is the reversed version of yours. The clicking area set on the button itself and the button view on the :before pseudo.
You can style it however you want.

[Working Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/zeevkatz/1rz1kL22/)

**CSS:**

```
.example {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.example:before {
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  background: gainsboro;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.example:active:before {
  background: gray;
}
```

Comment: This is the exact thing I said I tried. Does not work on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Just add some padding to your button, you may need to change the background of the button to transparent or any other color / background;
Or add height and width;

Comment: I thought of that. But the button itself already uses padding for UI purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Add a transparent `border` to your `button` element, like so:

```css
body{
  background:#000;
  color:#000;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}
button{
  background:#fff;
  background-clip:padding-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border:10px solid transparent;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<button>text</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

change html

```
<button class="example">
    <span>OK</span>
</button>
```

add css

```
 .example span
{
  padding-top:50px;
  padding-bottom:50px;
}
```